# Why is the dictionary i created out of another dictionary using a for loop smaller?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
bus_stops = jsoncalls.get_bus_stop()
print(len(bus_stops))
stop_map = {stop['Description']: stop for stop in bus_stops}
print('extracted dic: '+str(len(stop_map)))
```

here is what my code looks like. basically i create a dictionary out of another method i have from an api call. then i did what i think was to create another dictionary populated with only the values "description" from that dictionary.

the first print is the length of the first dictionary. the second print is the length of the second.

```
5024
extracted dic: 4457
```

the second dictionary is 600 items short! i am perplexed as to what could have caused this. can anyone advice me?

Comment: keys are unique, I guess you have repeated descriptions in your source dict.

Comment: Is it possible that there are multiple stops with the same Description? Because adding a value for the same key twice to a dictionary, will overwrite the first value.

Comment: hmm actually you guys are right i should look at my dataset carefully and see if there are repeated descriptions.

Comment: for a dict keys are unique then if you have duplicated keys dict only store a once each key

Answer (score 2):

You're grouping the items by description by using it as a key. A key can only exist once. If two items have the same description, they'll occupy the same key, of which only the last one will survive.

Answer (score 0):

Since dict keys are unique, I would bet you have repeated descriptions in your source dict. For example, suppose you have the following dataset:

```
bus_stops = [
  {"Id": 1, "Description": "spam"},
  {"Id": 2, "Description": "cheese"},
  {"Id": 3, "Description": "spam"},
]
```

Note how only the last "spam" will be present in the result:

```
>>> stop_map = {stop['Description']: stop for stop in bus_stops}
{
   'cheese': {'Description': 'cheese', 'Id': 2},
   'spam': {'Description': 'spam', 'Id': 3}},
}
```

If this is the case and you want to group stops by description, you can use a dict with description as key and a list of stops as value - the `setdefault` method is handy for this kind of data transformation:

```
stop_map = {}
for stop in bus_stops:
    stop_map.setdefault(stop["Description"], []).append(stop)
```

Result:

```
{
    "cheese": [
        {
            "Id": 2, 
            "Description": "cheese"
        },
    ], 
    "spam": [
        {
            "Id": 1, 
            "Description": "spam"
        }, 
        {
            "Id": 3, 
            "Description": "spam"
        },
    ],
}
```